# SweetAlert2で改行コード（/n）がブラウザで改行されない。

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sweetalert1を使用していたときはこのコードで問題なく改行されていたのですが、
SweetAlert2にしてからはブラウザのtextの欄に/nがそのまま表示されてしまい、改行されなくなってしまいました。/nを(/n)にしてみたりもしたのですが、治りませんでした。

どうすれば正常に改行されるようになるのでしょうか？

```
swal({
title: "Hello!",
text: "Hello/nWorld!",
confirmButtonText: "閉じる",
});
```

Comment: 無事解決しました！user29553さん、情報提供していただきありがとうございました！

Comment: 質問が解決済みである事を示すには「承認」という操作を行ないます。詳しくは[「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧下さい。

Comment: ちなみに、`/n` がそのまま表示されたのは、JavaScript（やその他の多くの言語）の文字列で改行コードは `/n` ではなく、`\n` で表わすからです。スラッシュではなく、逆スラッシュ（環境によっては円マークの字形で表示されます）であることに注意して下さい。

Comment: すみません。返信が遅くなりました。教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように`text:`を`html:`に変更し、
改行タグ`<br>`を入れることで実現できます。

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.26.10/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.26.10/sweetalert2.css">


<script>
swal({
  title: "Hello!",
  html: "Hello<br>World!",
  confirmButtonText: "閉じる",
});
</script>
```